# How to enable GPUVideoDecode (hardware acceleration) with Chromium on Xubuntu 17.10?

Tags: intel-graphics, chromium, gpu-driver, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I'm trying to make the Hardware Video Decode works on an Intel NUC7i3 (with Intel HD Graphics 620). My goal is being able to play smoothly 4K H.264 videos in the browser.

Here is a summary of my situation:

- I've installed Xubuntu 17.10 (secure boot is disabled), third party drivers/codecs has been enabled during the installation.
- I've installed Chromium version 64 from [saiarcot895 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta) that has an hard-coded enabled hardware acceleration.
- I've switch to "Enable" the Chromium Flags "Accelerated Video Decode" and "Override Software Rendering List".
- chrome://gpu gives me "Video Decode: Hardware accelerated"
- I play a 4K H.264 video in a tab
- In another tab I user chrome://media-internals and I can read that FFMpegVideoDecode is use to play the video (software decoding).

I'm looking to obtain "GPUVideoDecode" instead of "FFMpeg..." which is the only reliable indicator that the hardware video decode is used.

How can I do the enable the hardware acceleration ?

Comment: Do you have _intel-microcode_ installed?

Comment: I've just installed it. Nothing better... any other advice?

Comment: Can you play the same video with ``mpv --hwdec=vaapi``? Just to check your intel driver is working.

Comment: yes mpv with vaapi worked. problem was about the version 64. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by upgrading to version 65 or 66.
According to the maintainer for this PPA, this problem is related to something which is probably missing in the 64 version.